# Show where the sun is on the sky in real time - how?

Tags: javascript, css, image, astronomy

I am using a function from [mourner/suncalc](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc) that allows me to get the current position of our sun. With `getPosition()`, I want to create an animation on a image or with pure CSS (scaleable to different screen resolutions and orientations, of course), where you can see where the sun is right now in real time on the page. A totally unnecessary function but a fun function :) The image below illustrates how I am thinking.

[image]

Like I said, I'll be using the `getPosition()` function from mourner's function which prints [azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) and altitude of the sun. The problem I am facing now, is to somehow convert this data to percents or pixels, so the sun in my example image above moves along the round line (and yes, the sun must be blocked by the straight line that imitates the ground), imitating the real position on the sky in real life.

The azimuth data looks like -0.7000179547193575 and the altitude like this: -0.699671080144066 (based on the current sun position where I am right now).

How do I accomplish this? Can I do this with pure CSS or do I have to do it with images?

Comment: mourner/suncalc is a JS Library, not a css Library, so pure css solution is nonsense

Comment: @MrJ for getting the data. Not for ... presenting it.

Comment: so, you want to get js data directly in css ???

Comment: You'll have to tell us how you intend to project a spherical coordinate to a 2D plane. It seems like you could for instance ignore the azimuth, unless you have an indication what is north on your image? And then, how will you know the sun is moving exactly according a semi-circle? In winter it will be a shorter arc, in summer a longer one. That is info you don't get from those coordinates...

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @pregmatch Maybe with the answer below, yes. Haven't worked with it yet because I need to do other stuff first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact formula but here is an idea how you can create this using CSS then you simply have to adjust different values.

```js
var sun = document.querySelector('.sun');

function update() {
  var x = Math.random() * 180;
  var y = Math.random() * 40;
  sun.style.transform="rotateX("+y+"deg) rotate("+x+"deg)"
}
```

```css
.container {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid;
}
.sun {
  margin:20px;
  padding-top:calc(100% - 40px);
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  transform:rotateX(20deg) rotate(20deg);
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s;
}
.sun:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 20px);
  left:-20px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:yellow;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="sun">

</div>
</div>
<button onclick="update()">update</button>
```

Using the code below you simply need to convert your values to a degrees in order to rotate the `sun` element and place the sun in the correct place.

Comment: Very nice solution! But the sky line move up and down when I test your code here. Why? The sky line should be stationary :P

Comment: @Erik there is two rotation, I tried to make it more closer to the reality beause in reality the sun doesn't move following half a circle but it can be an ellipse depeding on complex stuff that's why I made two rotation .. but you can remove the X rotation to get only the other one ;)

Comment: @Erik check this image: https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/ua/EclipticOnSphere.png .. you will probably understand better in 3D ;)

Comment: Hehe. Thanks. But if I want to make the circular line stationary and not moving at all, I just delete the `x` line from your code?

Comment: @Erik yes, simply keep the second rotation

Comment: Thanks. But when I take the sun's altitude or azimuth and put it in your code, the sun will always be at the horizon (like on my example image but the horizon covers 50% of the sun). Do you have any quick solution for this? Should I use math to convert the values somehow?

Comment: @Erik yes you will probably need math, I cannot help since it's a bit complicated and require some knowledge but the idea is to find how to convert your value into a degree that you can add to my code. Let's say that I have done half the road, now you need the other half

Comment: As I suspected, haha! Yepp :) I am very glad you helped me with this one. Once again, many thanks!